# use and operator in if condition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two combobox..and i have a add button..if both combobox having value then only

i want to add my combobox item to grid view ..so i given validation like this:

```
 If (cmbside.Text = " " And cmbDamage.Text = " ") Then
            MsgBox("Please Select Both Item", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
```

so this case if if i keep one combobox value blank ,
,then also another value is adding to grid view.

what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add both combobox value in gridview check the condition like this

```
 If ComboBox1.Text.Trim = String.Empty OrElse ComboBox2.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please Select Both Item", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case, but you should really use `OrElse` instead of `Or`.

Comment: ok,,sir,,thanks,,this got worked fine for me..thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's about " " ...

```
If cmbside.Text = "" And cmbDamage.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Both Item", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

or

```
If cmbside.SelectedIndex = -1 And cmbDamage.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Both Item", MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```